# Woocommerce doesn't work with theme, header missing and css messed up

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, themes, css, html

Basically I'm trying to make woocommerce work with my theme.

Summary:

> Header doesn't show up on product page and the css is kinda bad

I'm sorry if the post is long, when I ask something people always ask for more detail.

So far what I've done:
-Declared support in functions.php

```
function satelite_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'satelite_add_woocommerce_support' );
```

-Used hooks to hook into content (*possible mistake here*)

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);

add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'satelite_wrapper_start', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'satelite_wrapper_end', 10);

function satelite_wrapper_start() { 
    echo '<div id="post">';
    get_header();
}
function satelite_wrapper_end() {
    echo '</div>';
}
```

I said possible mistake here because of this line

```
echo '<div id="post">';
```

In the official documentation it said to adjust the markup so it fist my theme, me not really knowing what to do and seeing as "main" as suggested didn't work tried a bunch of options and concluded that "post" kinda works. When I say didn't work I mean that none of the css worked as expected, the page had no margins, etc.

## The Main Problem

On my products page, when I use define the product type as a normal woocommerce one, the header shows, although some of the css still doesn't work, for example the header overlaps the image. Now we come to the main problem, when I define the product as a rental type it has some of the same problems as before and the header doesn't show. Here are the examples:

[https://bosniabayti.com/product/audi-a6-copy/][1] - Normal woocommerce product type
[https://bosniabayti.com/product/audi-a6/][2] - RnB woocommerce extension product type

I've noticed when using inspect element that header-visible class is missing on the second type but I don't know how to add it and I want to know if I implemented woocommerce right by using "post".

If anyone needs and further files, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your observation is correct.
If you add "header-visible" class to body of https://bosniabayti.com/product/audi-a6/, then the header is visible similar to https://bosniabayti.com/product/audi-a6-copy/

[image: Screenshot of "header-visible" class added to <body> tag]

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, do you know where and how to add?

Comment: You should search for `"<body"` tag in your code and append `" header-visible"` class before the tag ends `">"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)